# How to test globals with Mocha?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

When testing with Mocha, how dose one load foo.js so that the foo-test.js can test global variables such as giveMeFive()?

foo.js:

```
function giveMeFive() {
    return 'High five!');
}
```

foo-test.js:

```
describe('#convertNumberToDollar()', function() {
  it('should get a successful high five', () => {
    assert.ok( giveMeFive() === 'High five!', ' successful high five.' );
  });
});
```

It would be ideal if the solution can be automated via Bamboo.

Comment: Are you running  Mocha in Node? In that case you can just use `require` (or `import` if you're using Babel)

Comment: Even if giveMeFive() is global?

Comment: Check my answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `import * as thisNameDoesntMatter from 'foo'` or, using es5 style (which is cleaner in this case), `require('foo')` and globals defined in that file will be available on the global scope.

For instance, if you define the following JavaScript file:

```
//test.js

aGlobalVariable = 'someValue';

let aLocalVariable = 'anotherValue';

export default aLocalVariable;
```

This is the code Babel will generate (using the `es2015` preset and the `"node"` environment):

```
//test-compiled.js
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
global.aGlobalVariable = 'someValue';

var aLocalVariable = 'anotherValue';

exports.default = aLocalVariable;
```

As you can see, the `aGlobalVariable` declaration is kept in the module. As the entire compiled file will be evaluated when it's imported, `aGlobalVariable` will be available on the global scope whenever you import this module (if you chose the `"browser"` environment, it would be defined on `window`). You don't need to explicitly request the globals to be imported.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response. My question is how to test globals with Mocha? How do I load the foo.js that contains the global variables? I'm working with legacy code that is full of many files with many globals.

Comment: You can just load the file the same way you would load a file that exports a module. If the file contains globals, those globals will be set on the `global` (in Node) or `window` (in the browser`) object as usual. I edited my answer to address that.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about import * as a solution. For my needs, this did not work for some reason, but gulp-mocha-phantomjs helped me run my Mocha html test runner in Node. Cheers!